# Firebase Function to get UTC time

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, function

My Firebase Function code:

**My question is inside the code below**

```
exports.scheduledFunction= functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
    var snapshot= firebase.doc(something/somethingID).get();
    var timestamp=snapshot[‘timestamp’];
    //my question begins here:
    //how can I make this condition
     
    if(timestamp(according UTC time)<Current UTC time){
        //do something 
    }
});
```

And my firestore timestamp field:
[18 February 2021 00:00:00 UTC +4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFV0W.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore `TimeStamp` has two properties `nanoseconds` and `seconds`, we shall use any one for the comparison

```js
var timestamp = snapshot[‘timestamp’];

// fetch seconds and convert it into milliseconds
var time_in_millis  = timestamp._seconds * 1000
     
if(time_in_millis < Date.now()){
    //do something 
}
```

- `Date.now()` - method returns the number of milliseconds of UTC time since Unix epoch

Comment: Thank You very much! İ have one question timestamp._second*1000 return value according UTC time? Because my timestamp field is UTC +4

Comment: Yes, the `timestamp` seconds field gices you the the number of seconds of UTC time since Unix epoch. A nice explanation about `Firestore Timestamp` is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714631/firestore-timestamp-fromdate-not-utc