# how to add current DateTime to firestore document?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I'm adding a document to a firestore collection from my flutter app,
and one of the document fields holds a timestamp.

```
final dateTime = await Services.getTime();   //dateTime = 2021-10-11 12:16:00.000

await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('trialUsers').doc('someRandomID').set({
          "name": user.user.displayName,
          "email": user.user.email,
          "creationDate": dateTime,
          
        }).then((value) => print(dateTime));
```

but on my firestore document the timeStamp is one hour less than dateTime.
[image]

I don't know why firestore subtracts (1 hour) from the original dateTime.
How Do I Solve That?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore Timestamp.fromDate not UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714631/firestore-timestamp-fromdate-not-utc)

Answer (score 0):

To use a Timestamp from firestore, Change this line:

```
"creationDate": dateTime,
```

into this:

```
"creationDate": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Comment: I tried it and it gives me the same result, minus one hour.