# Firestore - How to write a query to get values in between the defined time range

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(userId)
            .where(
              'Time',isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDate,
            )
            .snapshots(),
```

I want to get all the values from the database so that I can build a graph of the defined range. But firebase is returning all the values.

Comment: You are talking about a range, but you are only using the startDate. Do you also have an endDate?

Comment: even this query is not working.

Comment: What's the format of `Time`? Is it lowercase or uppercase (which may influence how it's fetched)? Has Firestore created an index for the `Time` column? Where is `startDate` declared? What format is `startDate` in? Is it a timestamp or an absolute second value?

Comment: Time is in Timestamp , it i'm using the same name as it is declared in Firestore , I have also tried by converting my startDate value to timestamp and then fetching it.

Comment: Two things to note: make sure to put an `endDate`, because if your start date is too early then it has nowhere to stop; and please keep in mind that [Firebase does not use UTC, nor really interpret Timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714631/firestore-timestamp-fromdate-not-utc), it uses absolute seconds, iirc. So I believe if your `startDate` starts with `0`, then you'll fetch everything. Try using `GreaterThan` instead of `GreaterThanOrEqualTo`. Does this still cause issues for you?